# Pandas groupby rows with csv

Tags: python, csv, pandas, group-by, aggregate

I have a large CSV file that I am pulling two columns from (Month and Cancelled) and needing to display the results in a dataframe. The months are integer (eg. January is 1 in the csv) and need to convert it to a string.

What I'm having trouble with is setting the correct indices and grouping the data from the months together.

```
    import pandas as pd
    data = pd.read_csv('data.csv', encoding='latin-1', usecols=['Month','Cancelled'])
    grouped = data.groupby(axis=1)
```

The expected output I'm looking for is along the lines of:

```
               Cancelled
    January        19891
```

But I am currently receiving:

```
        Month  Cancelled
    0       1          0
    1       1          0
    2       1          0
```

Comment: Post your raw input data just enough to reproduce your problem, you've not shown how your integer is being converted to a month for a start, also you're not grouping on any column, you stated you wanted to groupby the month column

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't post a row input data. Let's consider this quick example just to show how to make groupby values in pandas;

After reading your data and puting in a dataframe, you can groupby values based on one of the columns `groupby(['month'])`, and then apply a function on these values,Pandas includes a number of common ones such as mean(), max(), median(), etc.: you can use `sum()` for example.

```
 df.groupby(['month']).sum()
```

Or pass any other function using aggregate

```
df.groupby(['month']).aggregate(numpy.sum)

import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO


data="""month  cancelled
0    1      1
1    1      0
2    0      1
3    1      1
4    0      0
5    1      1
6    1      1
7    2      1
8    2      1
9    1      1"""


df= pd.read_csv(StringIO(data.decode('UTF-8')),delim_whitespace=True )
print df.groupby(['month']).sum()
```

**RESULT**

```
       cancelled
month           
0              1
1              5
2              2
```